# Securing Applications behind a "https" - Wall

Tags: proxy, https

First of all, sorry for my sloppy title, but I can not figure out a better description.

My problem is the following. I like to deploy some services in a home network, which are accessible via http. Those services should not be accessed by the outer world, but through a "https gateway", meaning a server which is listening on a public ip, but only allowing client access the services via https. So that might be something like an http proxy tunneled by https? Anyway. How could I achieve this setup? I have two additional requiments. The gateway should be able to work with client certificates for authentication, and allow to extend the authorization part, for a custom method.

Thanks! If something is unclear, give me a comment and I will clarify it, but right now that the best I could formulate.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.

Comment: sorry I will move the question, was not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule)?

You can run nginx as a reverse proxy / SSL Offloader where the clients talk HTTPS (and it can check client certificates) to the proxy and the proxy talks HTTP to the backend(s).

You can create your own modules for use with nginx as well so you could develop a custom authorization module if you want. Here is a [list](http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules) of some third-party modules.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that helped! the page is here: http://wiki.nginx.org/SSL-Offloader

Comment: In the end I used nginx and also installed the request-module which allows to make a seperate request for the authentication, which than is asking a fastcgi script to validate if the user has the sufficiant credentials Thanks